# Sync SharePoint Tasks and Outlook Tasks 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, outlook, synchronization

Hj,

I want to Sync SharePoint Tasks and Outlook Tasks 2010 but the custom columsn in SP do not exist in outlook. Did anyone have a solution for this stuff. :)

Many thanks.

Comment: Has this changed for Outlook 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any third party software you can not do that. But there is a work around:

- On SP go to ~'Add Existing Columns' -> Choose ~'Core Task Columns' -> add some columns from there to your list. You can rename added columns as you wish but you can not change their type.
- Sync your list with Outlook & create some dummie entries to test it.
- Now you can check how Tasks are represented on Outlook. You can find entries in task form. Go to: Show -> Details, Task.
- If you want to add a control to your list items such as a dropbox or date, you can do that with Outlook custom forms. But in SP task list column value will be represented as single line of text.

Unfortunatelly you have to give a lot for custom values :)

Answer (score 1):

Feature for users with Outlook 2010, iPhone, and SharePoint 2010 project list/task.

I was able to get SharePoint 2010 list/ task items to show up on the iPhone ios5 reminders.app

Step One- is go to SharePoint 2010 site and Connect to Outlook 2010

http://epmsource.com/2011/02/09/sync-project-tasks-to-outlook-without-exchange/

Step Two- is check for the linked SharePoint task to be added to users SharePoint List in Outlook

Step Three- is to drag SharePoint List in Outlook Normal task.

Step Four- is the final view of the users outlook account folder hierarchy

Step Five- on the iPhone go to settings.app àexchange mail à turn on Reminders

Step Six- on the iPhone go to reminders.app à swipe left to see second SharePoint list task.

Only problem is the you will notice that the projects under my task doesn’t have the blue two arrows anymore. That’s because it’s not going to talk to SharePoint anymore. When I move it to my mailbox the it got disconnected. If I get it to work I will update you. But who knows may your views can found a fix faster.